# Как скрыть TextBox?

Tags: c#

Есть разные радио_кнопки... Так же есть и два текстбокса
Работа по примеру калькулятора
Нужно при выборе одной из радио_кнопок (для квадратного корня) - скрывался текстбокс_номер_2, как будто бы  его и не было.

Помогите пожалуйста решить?

Comment: 16 вопросов, 0% принятых. Нет, тебе не помогут.

Comment: А у тебя не кто и не спрашивал.

Comment: @extazys, что надо сделать, чтобы получить бан во всех поисковиках?

Comment: пугалка еще не выросла.

Comment: Попринимаете ответы, глядиш и помогут, а пока что даже ссылку на гугл лень кидать :)

Comment: куда этот мир катится - уже гопота в программирование полезла

Comment: @Flammable  а вам ни пофиг на количество принятых? Что-то все чаще стал замечать такие сообщения

Comment: @rasmisha, нет, мне не пофиг.

Comment: @Flammable а какой смысл? Люди начинают отмечать любые ответы, даже которые не дают ответа на вопрос. По мне лучше вопрос с непринятым ответом, чем вопрос с неверно принятым. Кстати, у вас тоже принято 0%, пусть не из  такого количества. Удачи в погоне за циферками

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обрабатываешь изменение радио кнопки и скрываешь TextBox по id
TextBoxId.Visible = false;

Comment: спасибо!       .